# Dealloc not called changing tab

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, dealloc

Let's suppose to have a tab bar controller with two tabs, A and B, where A is a navigation controller.

When the user is in A, he can push A1 and then A2, which are both view controllers.
A back button on A2, performs:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

which correctly triggers the dealloc method on A2.

If the user is in A2 and then switches to tab B, I need the dealloc method to be called on A2; therefore I've implemented the following method in the TabBarController:

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    UINavigationController *nc = (UINavigationController*)tabBarController.selectedViewController;
    [nc popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    return YES;
}
```

but in this flow the dealloc method of A2 is never called!
How is it possible that popping from A2 to A1 it works, whereas changing tabs the view controller is not deallocated?

Thanks for any hint!

DAN

Comment: Have you tried using Instruments to track down references to A2?

Comment: @MikePollard, I stumbled over your comment which is interessing. How can you track down references to ViewControllers using instruments? I have a similar issue and would like to use your approach.

Comment: @JFS I'd go with the Leaks tool

Comment: @MikePollard with instruments I've been able to find out that the retain counter for A2 is 1 after I changed the tab: that could be the reason for the missing deallocation; is it possible to know the owner of such retain?

Comment: If it could be of any help, A2 is pushed through a Segue created in a Storyboard; on the other hand popToRootViewController is performed programmatically.

Comment: I'm sure with Insturments you can find out what has retained, but not released A2?

Comment: Instruments tells me that the view controller is still living, even if  the user has changed tab, and the responsible caller which retains it is the following:
`-[UIClassSwapper initWithCoder:]`
Any idea?

Comment: When the user changes tab, both `shouldSelectViewController` and `didSelectViewController` methods are executed before the new tab appears (try placing breakpoints), therefore I think that `popToRootViewControllerAnimated` can't really release a view controller being showed.
If that's the reason for dealloc not being called, I can't pop the view controllers that way.. mumble..

Comment: too localized, this won't help anybody

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `didSelectViewController` is triggered before the tab controller has switched to the destination tab.
Therefore the execution of the method `popToRootViewControllerAnimated` correctly pops all the view controllers, but can't really release the visible one, as it is currently being depicted by the app.

To achieve my result, I've figured out the following solution.
In the `viewDidAppear` method of all the view controllers which correspond to the first view controller for each tab, I execute `popToRootViewControllerAnimated` (all of them are navigation controller).

Answer (score 1):

dealloc is only for removing observers and freeing memory -- when or if it is called is up to the runtime

e.g.
think of the cases of release vs. autorelease (influence when it is called) or if you terminate an app (not called at all)

instead on relying on dealloc, write a method you explicitly call.. e.g. something like stop or finish or cleanup

or... use viewDidDisappear.

**-- in any case, don't rely on dealloc**

Comment: viewDidDisappear is not called either! I need the dealloc to be called for removing observers, as you said.

Comment: no. you misunderstand: dont rely on dealloc to be called at a certain time. period. though that viewDidDisappear is not called is weird

Comment: yes, that is weird, and probably caused by the popToRootViewController to be called during tab switching (a vc cannot disappear while it is displayed).