# deinit in child view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, observers, deinit

I have a tab bar controller and one of the tabs consists of a table view. When clicking on a row I segue to a new child controller.

In this new controller, I have a deinit which removes an observer and prints "controller is de-initialised here".

I can see when I press the back button in the navbar that the de-init is called on this action.

Now... I have another method within that child controller which sets the active tab of the tab bar controller. When this action happens, I do not see the print statement indicating the de-init is not being called in that case.

I'm wondering how to solve this? I'm worried that I'm holding onto extra stuff in memory if deinit isn't called.

**Update:**
In my method for setting the active tab, I would also like to popToRoot on the current active child controller. I tried the following:

```
self.navigationController!.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2
```

And I get the following error:

```
popViewControllerAnimated: called on <UINavigationController 0x15609a200> while an existing transition or presentation is occurring; the navigation stack will not be updated.
```

This makes sense but I'm wondering, is there any way around this?

**Update 2**

In order to avoid the issue above, I put popToRoot in my observer and added the tabbar.setSelectedIndex to the viewDidDisappear instead.

```
func checkForSeg(){
      //self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2
      self.navigationController!.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
 }

 override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
      super.viewDidDisappear(true)
      print("view Did Disappear called?")
      self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2
 }
```

But I do not understand why the tab bar isn't switching index when I press the nav back bar button(I don't want it to and it isn't but I dont understand why?)

When I explicitly call popToRoot in the checkForSeg func, then the viewDidDisappear executes the line 'tabbar.setSelectedIndex' (as desired) but when I press the nav back bar button it doesn't (also desired). I don't understand why this is? As I have not implemented any custom logic for when it should or shouldn't perform the tab change.

Also, I **AM** getting the print statement every time.

Comment: You should not rely on deinit to remove observers. You can use a custom method that is called explicitly to do so. Refer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/18560069/5060335

Comment: @Udits I can put in the remove observer in my method where I am setting the active tab, no problem, but I was just worried about the other things that happen in the background when deinit is called. (arc doing its thing, freeing up of memory mainly) and how I could set the active tab when in a child view controller the most efficient way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you switch tabs in a `UITabBarController`, you do not release the previous **tab's controller** from memory.

This is **expected** behavior.

If you move back to the tab you are referring to you will see that the child VC is still alive and well.

The **current active** VC of any tab will always stay resident in memory during the execution of the application.

Thus, at a minimum, when using `UITabBarControllers`, the root viewController on each tab is held in memory and only released on application termination, or termination of the tabBarController.

No issue here.

Comment: thank you for your response. i'm just trying to make it all crystal clear in my head.. So what I would like to happen is in my method for setting the active tab and removing an observer, I also want to popToRoot so that child controller is no longer active after switching tabs. I'll update the question to reflect the new issue after reading and understanding things a bit better from reading your answer

Comment: @user2363025 - no probs! - yes that is the answer, if you also pop to root VC then the child controller will be destroyed.

Comment: I put the popToRoot in the method where I was switching tabs and moved the tabController.setSlectedIndex into my viewdidDisappear, thanks!

Comment: sorry but I have one additional question. My approach of adding the setSelectedIndex in my viewDidDisappear is working as I want it to. However..I don't understand why when I press the nav back bar button in the child view controller and exit that screen normally, the tab bar does not switch? As I do not have any conditions in viewDidDissappear of whether or not to set the selected index.. Hope I have explained myself clearly.

Comment: I don't fully understand, can you add code and question to the above?